# Unable to use plugin in flutter because of older version of Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Everyone I am getting the following error when running a project in flutter:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':sql_conn' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

I attempted to edit the build grade file in project/android/build.grade using the following code but I am still getting the error. This has been the fix I have seen in all my searches. I am using plugin  sql_conn. All I want to do is be able to show data from a sql database in an app.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means that you are using a package that uses kotlin version *1.3.50* but your current project needs kotlin version >= *1.5.20*. So you have to either update that package (if it's possible or use another one) or downgrade your project specifications.